# preg_replace: add whitespace into paragraphs

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Can i add whitespace into all paragraphs?

I have a string like this:

```
<p>1st paragraph</p>
<p></p>
<p>2nd paragraph</p>
<p></p>
<p>3rd paragraph</p>
```

and i want get the result like a white space inside all paragraphs

```
<p> 1st paragraph</p>
<p> </p>
<p> 2nd paragraph</p>
<p> </p>
<p> 3rd paragraph</p>
```

does someone know how to do it with `preg_replace` or something else better?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: isn't the simplest approach not:  `str_replace('<p>', '<p> ', $yourstring);`

Comment: @OscarHo, if you take a look at [mcve], it will help improve the quality of your questions. When someone gives you an answer that works, it's considered good form to "accept" that answer so the person gets reputation points and other readers know which answer may work for them.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution to this is:

```
<?php
$markup = <<<HTML
<p>1st paragraph</p>
<p></p>
<p>2nd paragraph
which spans over
three line</p>
<p></p>
<p>3rd paragraph</p>
HTML;

$result = preg_replace('|<p>(.*?)</p>|us', '<p> $1</p>', $markup);
var_dump($result);
```

The output of above code is:

```
string(111) "<p> 1st paragraph</p>
<p> </p>
<p> 2nd paragraph
which spans over
three line</p>
<p> </p>
<p> 3rd paragraph</p>"
```

Comment: You didn't consider multiline paragraphs... and why matching parts after opening `<p>`?

Comment: facebook's instant article warning the paragraphs tag cant be empty and i have many paragraphs tag does not contain any text

Comment: @revo about capturing the parts after the opening tag... sure possible to simply replace the tag and all is fine. But in the end this depends a bit on what the OP wants _exactly_. Since that is vague I prefer above solution.